# How can I read a message (in HTML format) from gmail gmail-api using python (v3.7)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, html-email, gmail-api

I tried to follow the orientation followed in the link below but I did not succeed.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

Can someone help me by "being very specific" in what I should do to read the body message (in HTML format)?

**I already have the message**

[image: image_description]

**message content**

[image: image_description]

**message content type**

[image: image_description]

Thank you very much!

Comment: You mean that you received the answer? Or does it raise an exception?

Comment: Hello @A.Wolf a received, But after this point i would like to "transform" the content in HTML for i save in the database.

Comment: Can You add an example of response? Of course, replace sensible data with placeholders. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @A.Wolf I updated the question with this new information.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up answering my question... Look below what I did to read a message using gmail's api.

In some situations the best response is in a good night's rest, a bit of insistence and the letitura of documentations.

[Image with the programming](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywVLQ.png)

Thank you very much @A.Wolf!

Comment: Glad to hear that! I'm sorry, I couldn't help you more in previos days. For next questions I suggest you to add code, output and other staff as code, not as image, because it simpler to help you trying the same code you're using. You can simply add code clicking on the brackets in the editor, surround the code with <pre> <code> tag or with ` characters.